# Path cannot be recognized because of the & sign

Tags: ios, bash, path

I have an & in the file name and when I type the path that is verified to the command line, it does not recognize it.

Here is the path:

> /Users/wendywang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ConsumeriOS-cchvkfmgubtyzydmbsgaxxxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PG&E.app

It shows the error that

> Specified target process is invalid
>
> E.app: command not found

It is not working because of the &. I was wondering how to deal with the & here? Thanks!

Comment: try "hard-quoting" your the full path/file reference, i.e. `'/Users/....PG&E.app'` . Also, this isn't a programming question, so please learn to ask on the right forum, this would be more appropriate on the Stackexchange related site http://superuser.com. Good luck.

Comment: You should be able to *escape* the ampersand: `...PG\&E.app`.

Comment: @chrisaycock yes it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For clarification I will reproduce the problem with a strangely named file and then attempt to execute it. Observe:

```
echo 'echo hello' > 'qaz&bar'

chmod +x 'qaz&bar'

./'qaz&bar'
```

Or specify its full path:

```
/home/none/StackExchange/qaz\&bar
```

Notice the `\` is escaping the special `&` character.

To make a copy of files as follows:

```
cp '/home/none/StackExchange/qaz&bar' normal_name
```

Essentially one can use either single ticks `''`or backslash `\` characters to help manipulate filenames like this and prevent special characters from being interpreted by the shell.